# Artefacts when printing parallel to X axis

Tags: print-quality, tronxy-x1

If you can help me with troubleshooting the artefact shown in the attached photo that would be great. It only happens when I print the Benchy parallel to the X axis and when I print parallel to Y axis it prints just fine.

Notes:

- 3D printer: TronXY X1
- Filament: PLA
- Extruder temp: 195°C, 200°C, 205°C - doesn't matter same results.
- Slicer: Ideamaker

[image: Benchy objects showing printing artefact]

Answer (score 5):

I have a TronXY X1 myself. This kind of artifacts appear along the X-Axis as it is a cantilever design - and if not properly secured, will start to osctilate when moving sharply. This can be fixed in several ways:

- print slower. By making the movement changes less abrupt, the oscilation can be reduced.
- stiffen the X on the Z. Often, the X1 has a somewhat wobbly X-Axis. To fix this, someone calling themselves FabianFriethjoph did design a 'bracket' that is intended to keep the wheels aligned and under a little tension. https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2275654

Comment: I printed these at 35 mm/s so i don't think its the speed. however i didn't think the wobble was that bad. I will print the bracket and report back as soon as i finish it.